# The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory

Tags: android, flutter, macos, dart, flutter-exception

This problem occurred in only one project, knowing that there are 3 different projects in the same folder, all of them work without a problem
As for this project, I have a problem: Exception: The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
I run flutter doctor and everything is fine

how I can solve this problem?

Comment: It will be lovely if I could get to see a screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: Do you mean the info of the folder?

Comment: More of the folder arrangement info. How do you structure all they 3 different projects?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.